# Sentry logging configuration in SpringBoot application

Tags: spring-boot, sentry

I have an Spring Boot application:

```
Spring Boot 2.3.2.RELEASE
sentry-spring 1.7.30
sentry-logging 1.7.30
```

I'd like to set dsn in application.yml:

```
sentry:
   dsn: ${DSN}
```

but it doesn't work.
It works only if I create sentry.properties with same property (hardcoded).
My question is what's wrong with yml config?

Answer (score -2):

I probably think you've written DSN with `""`. If you want to use it in `application.yml`, do it without `""`.

```
sentry:
  dsn: "https://examplePublicKey@o0.ingest.sentry.io/0"   //wrong

sentry:
  dsn: "https://examplePublicKey@o0.ingest.sentry.io/0"   //ok
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Hesam but I don't see any difference between the wrong and the OK solution.